# How to submit tinyEditory's content through ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, tinymce

I have integrated StfalconTinymceBundle in one of my symfny2 project which work prefectly. But facing issue while submitting editor's content through ajax. Editor's content is not binding with post data in ajax. 
Please suggest solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced same issue with symfony2's StfalconTinymceBundle while ajax.
I hope below solution will solve your issue.

tinyMCE.triggerSave();

your have to trigger save event before ajax call.

Enjoy!